# Eloquent eager load constrain by parent column values

Tags: laravel, orm, eloquent, laravel-5

I'm on Laravel 5.2 and I'm having a problem using Eloquent to retrieve data with eagerly loaded relationships which need to be constrained by values from other relations.  I'm not sure of the proper term for this relation pattern and thus it's been difficult to locate a solution to this.

### Architecture

The code and tables/models are simplified for clarity:

**Three tables/models**:

E, D, and M.

**Relations**:

```
class D extends Model
{
  public function E()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\E');
  }
}

class E extends Model
{
  public function D()
  {
    return $this->hasMany('App\D');
  }
  public function M()
  {
    return $this->hasMany('App\M');
  }
}

class M extends Model
{
  public function E()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\E');
  }
}
```

Schema example `D <*--1> E <1--*> M`

There is no direct relation between D and M.

### Problem

I want a listing of D, with E and then M eagerly loaded into the properties of the D objects such that $D->E->M is a listing of M belonging to that E, which in turn D belongs to.

The problem is **I need the eager loading for M to be constrained by values from columns on D.**

Example:

```
$D = \App\D::with(['E' => function($query) {

  $query->with(['M' => function($query) {

    //example of what I'd like to do (but doesn't work)
    $query->where('start_timestamp','>=','D.start_timestamp'); 

  }]);

}])->get();
```

In that example, it attempts to compare M's `start_timestamp` field to the string 'D.start_timestamp', instead of D's `start_timestamp` value.

### Question

Is it possible to accomplish constraining an eager load by earlier related column values?  If so, how?

### I have tried...

...using $query->whereRaw to explicitly reference the earlier table's columns

```
$query->whereRaw('M.start_timestamp >= D.start_timestamp')
```

but this errors out with 'D.start_timestamp' as an unknown column.

...using whereColumn, but this doesn't seem to work with eager loading constraints (errors out with unknown column 'column').

---

I am trying to solve this problem in the "Eloquent way", avoiding the use of raw SQL and joins.  I know how to solve this via SQL and joins but I'd rather avoid it if possible.

Any help you can offer would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: did you created any relationships in your requested models ? if yes, please share your relationship

Comment: Yes I have, I edited the question to provide code for the relationships.

Comment: there's no eloquent way for eager loading like this. You can use `whereHas`, but it's hard to tell what you really need from your post. Better show real models names and code you are trying to run with result vs. expeceted result.

Comment: Thanks, I suspected as much.  What I need is listed under "Problem", I need to eager load while doing a `where` that references columns from other tables.  However, judging by the SQL generated, that doesn't seem possible as the eager load query seems independent of the first query.

Answer (score -1):

your above question statement is confusing alot, but as per my understanding you want to eager load `M` record from `D`, means `D -> E -> M` and there is no direct relations between `D` and `M`. You can do this

eg:

> D has relationship with E

and

> E has relationship with M

and you want to load all related records, you can do this

```
D::with(
     //this will fetch E records which belongs to D
     ['E'=>function($q){
         //your desire query, which you want to apply on E model/records
         $q->where('status','1')->where('problemname', '<>',null);

        },

     //this will fetch M records which belongs to E
     'E.M'=>function($q){
         //your desire query, which you want to apply on M model/records
         $q->where('status','1')->where('details', '<>',null);
        },
     ])->get();
```

your results will look like this

Parent will contains D records

```
Array(
   'name'=>'test',
   'email'=>'test@test.com',
   'dob'=>'1990-01-01',

   'E'=>Array(
         'problemname'=>'test',
         'problemtitle'=>'hello',
         'status'=>'1',
         ...

         'M'=>Array(
                'details'=>'test',
                'address'=>'hello',
                'status'=>'1',
                ...
              )
        )
)
```

Comment: Sorry, not sure how to make it more clear, it's my first time asking a question and it's hard to put into words. Yes your examples will work, and I already have reached that point. What I needed was to only fetch certain M records based on values contained in D. So if, for example, a D record has a field `status` = `10`, I might want to eager load M records that have their own field `status` that is greater than the D record's `status` field (10).  But appears that there's no way to access the results of the D query from the query that eager loads M results.